# C++ Programming Book Example on Stack

Tags: c++, syntax-error

In this book, I am learning how the book writes a stack, but when I compile it, it reaches a compile error:

```
#define DEFAULT_SIZE = 10

class Stack
{
    private:
        int size;
        int top;
        int *value;

    public:
        Stack( int size = DEFAULT_SIZE );
        virtual ~Stack();
        bool isFull();
        bool isEmpty();
        void push(int);
        int pop();
};
```

and the errors indicates:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Eddy\Desktop\C++ Playground\Data Structures\stack.h|14|error: expected primary-expression before '=' token|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I am using Code::Blocks as my IDE, and I believe that you cant initlize inside a class, and to create a "DEFAULT_SIZE" would be commonly in a default constructor.

Do I have the right idea? or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
#define DEFAULT_SIZE 10
```

The `=` sign is not needed in the preprocessor definition.

Answer (score 3):

The `#define` line is wrong. You don't need the equals symbol `=`.